# Get all documents of a type in mongoose but only with 1 specific item of each documents array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using Express 4 and Mongoose for my REST API. So I have multiple documents of the type "shop". Each shop holds (besides other information) an array called "inventory" that holds again multiple items. Each item itself has properties like name and price.

Now I would like to have an API call where I can get all the shops but only with their "cheapest" product item in the json response. But I'm totally stuck in creating this query that returns all my shops but instead of including all items of the inventoryjust includes the inventory item with the lowest price as the only item in the inventory array.

I found some hints on how to exclude fields using something like the following query but there the whole array will be excluded:

```
Shop.find({},  {inventory: 0},function(err, shops) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.json(shops);
    }
});
```

Update 1: My Schemas

```
// Shop
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    address: {
        street: String,
        zipCode: Number,
        city: String
    },
    inventory: [InventoryItemSchema]
});

// InventoryItem
var InventoryItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    currentPrice: {
        amount: { type: Number, required: true },
        added: Date
    },
    pastPrices: []
});
```

Update 2: This is what I came up

```
Shop.find(function(err, shops) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {

        shops.forEach(function(shop) {
            // Only keep the currently cheapest inventory Item in the array
            var cheapestInventoryItem;
            shop.inventory.reduce(function (previousItem, currentItem) {
                if (currentItem.currentPrice.amount < previousItem.currentPrice.amount) {
                    cheapestInventoryItem = currentItem;
                    return currentItem;
                } else {
                    cheapestInventoryItem = previousItem;
                    return previousItem;
                }
            });
            shop.inventory = [cheapestInventoryItem];
        });

        res.json(shops);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb find method returns a document. So in your case it would be array of shops with their fold fields anyway.

You can filter items with js:

```
var cheapestItem;
var cheapestPrice = shop.inventory.items.reduce(function (lowest, item) {
    if (item.price < lowest) {
        cheapestItem = item;
        return item.price;
    }
}, Infinity);
```

Or you can normalize your schema and create collection Items:

```
[{itemId: 1, shopId: 1, price: 100}]
```

So the query is:

```
db.Item.group(
{
     key: { shopId: 1, itemId: 1, price: 1 },
     reduce: function ( lowest, res ) { if (result.price < lowest) return result.price },
     initial: Infinity
})
```

So you must get shopId and itemId with lowest price

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get this... I just updated my original post with my Schemas. What do you mean with "normalize your schema"?

Comment: Nice, I mean the same. You should just add shopId to InventoryItem and use mongo grouping. if it suits your business logic

Comment: I think I'm to big of a noob to get this the right way. However, thanks to your hint with the reduce function, I managed to get what I wanted (see my original post). Most definitely not the best way, but it works. So thanks a lot!